# Select/MultiSelect Not Working in JPA (Spring Boot)

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I am using JPA specification in a Spring Boot project. All the criterias are working fine. But the issue is with select/multiselect.

Code -

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TodoSpecifications implements Specification<Todo> {
@Override
  public Predicate toPredicate(
      Root<todoEntity> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
    List<Predicate> predicateList = createPredicateList(root, criteriaBuilder);


    List<Selection<? extends Object>> selectionList = new ArrayList<Selection<? extends Object>>();
      Selection<? extends Object> selection = root.get("id");
      selectionList.add(selection);
    Selection<? extends Object> selection2 = root.get("name");
    selectionList.add(selection2);
    Selection<? extends Object> selection3 = root.get("type");
    selectionList.add(selection3);

    return query.multiselect(selectionList).where(criteriaBuilder.and(predicateList.toArray(new Predicate[] {}))).getRestriction();
  }
}
```

With this specification I tried this 
List toDoEntity = todoRepository.findAll(todoSpecification);
This will return full data. But I expect only selected columns.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a constructor that take 3 parameters?
To be able to use multiselect, you have to create a constructor in your `TodoEntity` like this

```
public TodoEntity (Long id, String name, String type) {
this.id = id;
this.name =  name;
this.type = type;
}
```